# how to make a read only textbox in gridview edit mode?

Tags: c#, textbox, edit

I want to make one of the data bound in my gridview uneditable or in my case, I want to make the textbox in edit mode in read only. here is what I have tried but not successful:

```
TextBox ProductImage = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        ProductImage.ReadOnly = true;
```

and here is the aspx code:

```
asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductImage" SortExpression="ProductImage">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductImage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ProductImage") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ControlStyle Width="50px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting ReadOnly to true in your aspx code?

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Eval("ProductImage") %>'/>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Or you could use a Label instead of a TextBox

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductImage") %>'/>
```